# What is a good way to organize your repo for interview questions?

Tags: git, repository, odoo

recently i got a job interview excercise. In this excersice, I was requested to add some field and auto update it. here is the request:

> Create an Odoo app that extends the functionalities of OpenG2P's registry. (https://github.com/openg2p/openg2p-registry)
>
> Add a field to the Individual page to store his yearly revenue;
> Add a button on the individual page to update the field from this mock API: https://62fb920fabd610251c0c306d.mockapi.io/api/v1/individual/1
> (replace ID with the id of the individual modulo 100 as there are only 100 individuals in the mock API);
> Use OCA/Queue (https://github.com/OCA/queue) to periodically update the data in a batch every 24h, make sure to limit the number of queries per job to 20. When all the jobs are finished, post a message in the discuss #general chat.
> Create a private repository and invite  as a collaborator.

And here is my repo for the excercise:
https://github.com/thainguyentran/newlogic

After I sent them the repo for the excercise, they say that they will not going forward with my application. I asked for the feedback on the code I did and any other reason for which I was rejected for the position. This is their reply:

> After submission of your exercise, we did submit it to the technical team for review, and the feedback included:
>
> lack of organization in the repository.
>
> For this reason, it has been decided not to shortlist your application for the role.

So may I ask what am I missing in term of ogarnization of repository? Please help me take a look at my repo and tell me what am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your github link, you did not perform these specific actions according to the given instruction.

> Create a private repository and invite as a collaborator.

Your repo is public and there is no other collaborator. So, maybe that's the point. I don't know if there are other factors that the company has to consider but, to know that information precisely, you would need to contact them.

Comment: I changed it to public after getting a reply from them. It was private when I sent it to them. About the collaborator, maybe they removed themself. If I don't set it to public, how will you or other people be able to see my code?